# Variable won't insert into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, variables

I have this script that takes a variable and puts it into a table. My connect.php file is correct and selects the right database, but for some reason this data will not insert. It says it succeeds but nothing gets put in the table

My Script

```
if(!empty($_POST['phrase'])){
    $phrase = $_POST['phrase'];
    $phrase = mysql_real_escape_string($phrase);
    $phrase = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", "", $phrase);
    $query5 = mysql_query('SELECT phrase FROM dictionary WHERE phrase = "'.$phrase.'" '); // Check the database 


    if(mysql_num_rows($query5)>0){
        null;
    }else{
        echo $phrase;
        $query10 = "INSERT into dictionary(adjective, noun, phrase, subject, verb) values(NULL, NULL, '$phrase', NULL, NULL)";
        $result = mysqli_query($query10); 
        echo "<pre>Debug: $query10</pre>\m";
        //$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if ( false===$result ) {
            printf("error: %s\n");
        }
        else {
            echo 'done.';
        }
        mysqli_close();
    }
    //Debugging Purpose
    echo '<span class="error" > -'. $phrase .'</span>';
}
```

It echos 'done.' but the table doesn't update

here is how my table is setup

```
-- Database: `dictionary`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dictionary` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `dictionary`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `adjective`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adjective` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`adjective` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `adjective` 
--

INSERT INTO `adjective` (`id`, `adjective`) VALUES
(1, 'orange'),
(2, 'blue');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `noun`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `noun` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`noun` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `noun`
--

INSERT INTO `noun` (`id`, `noun`) VALUES
(1, 'tamaleh');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `phrase`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phrase` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`phrase` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `phrase`
--

INSERT INTO `phrase` (`id`, `phrase`) VALUES
(0, 'Hello There'),
(1, 'Hello World');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `subject`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`subject` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subject`
--

INSERT INTO `subject` (`id`, `subject`) VALUES
(1, 'I'),
(2, 'The');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `verb`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `verb` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `verb` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `verb`
--

INSERT INTO `verb` (`id`, `verb`) VALUES
(1, 'jumping');
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` to find out more details. Also, obligatory link: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: It doesn't display that anything is wrong

Comment: You have `mysql_query` mixed with `mysqli_query` which are 2 different libraries, you should make use of `mysql_error()` like this `mysql_query('SELECT phrase FROM dictionary WHERE phrase = "'.$phrase.'" ') or die(mysql_error());` and `mysql_query($query10) or die(mysql_error());`also `printf("error: %s\n");` would never work as you give it no arguments to fill the `%s`

Comment: Aside from what I already pointed above your `INSERT` query is 1000% wrong dictionary is the database name not the table name and each column inside the parenthesis is a different table. Your `SELECT` query is also wrong there is no dictionary table so its only obvious it will fail.

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: @Prix Didn't check the database earlier. Now I get it. User confused himself with table being column, and his database as table.

Comment: @user3010773 what I can suggest is to merge into one table your adjective, noun, phrase, subject, and verb into one table. Then I'll fix my answer for you later on.

Comment: @LoganWayne Alright Ill try that

Comment: For example, create a TABLE named dictionaryTable and its column would be adjective, noun, phrase, subject and verb. I suggest dictionaryTable as your table name so you wouldn't confuse yourself again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Note:

- You have mixed `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` API.
- `mysql_*` is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and I'm recommending you to use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

Lets re-establish first your connection to MySQL database:

```
$con = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "dictionary"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA INSIDE */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then check each `POST` data from your form:

```
if(!empty($_POST["phrase"])){ /* IF SUBMITTED phrase DATA IS NOT EMPTY */

  /* LETS CHECK FIRST IF THE PASSED ON phrase DATA ALREADY EXIST IN THE phrase TABLE */
  if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM phrase WHERE phrase = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["phrase"]); /* BIND THE PASSED ON DATA TO THE QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
    $stmt->store_result(); /* STORE THE RESULT */
    $noofphrase = $stmt->num_rows; /* GET THE NUMBER OF RESULTS OF THE EXECUTE QUERY */

      if($noofphrase ==0){ /* IF phrase IS NOT YET IN THE phrase TABLE */
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO phrase (phrase) VALUES (?)"); /* START INSERT QUERY */
        $stmt2->bind_param("s", $_POST["phrase"]); /* BIND THE PASSED ON DATA TO THE QUERY */
        $stmt2->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE INSERT QUERY */
        $stmt2->close(); /* CLOSE THE INSERT QUERY PREPARED STATEMENT */
      }

    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
  } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

} /* END OF IF phrase IS NOT EMPTY */
```

Then repeat this for `adjective`, `noun`, `subject`, and `verb`.

## Less Tedious and Less Populated Code

It's a tedious work. The code will look populated. So why don't we just create a function where it will parametize the keyed-in data, table name, and column name. This is a better approach because they run in the same pattern.

```
<?php

  function CheckAndInsert ($data, $tablename, $columnname){

    global $con;

    if(!empty($data)){ /* CHECK IF KEYED-IN DATA IS NOT EMPTY */

      /* LETS CHECK FIRST IF THE PASSED ON phrase DATA ALREADY EXIST IN THE phrase TABLE */
      if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $tablename, $columnname, $data); /* BIND THE PASSED ON DATA TO THE QUERY */
        $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
        $stmt->store_result(); /* STORE THE RESULT */
        $noofresult = $stmt->num_rows; /* GET THE NUMBER OF RESULTS OF THE EXECUTE QUERY */

          if($noofresult ==0){ /* IF phrase IS NOT YET IN THE phrase TABLE */
            $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ? (?) VALUES (?)"); /* START INSERT QUERY */
            $stmt2->bind_param("sss", $tablename, $columnname, $data); /* BIND THE PASSED ON DATA TO THE QUERY */
            $stmt2->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE INSERT QUERY */
            $stmt2->close(); /* CLOSE THE INSERT QUERY PREPARED STATEMENT */
          } /* END OF CHECKING NO OF RESULTS FROM FIRST QUERY */

        $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
      } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

    } /* END OF CHECKING

  } /* END OF FUNCTION */

?>
```

So when user submits the form, just call this function.

```
CheckAndInsert($_POST["phrase"], "phrase", "phrase");
CheckAndInsert($_POST["adjective"], "adjective", "adjective");
CheckAndInsert($_POST["noun"], "noun", "noun");
CheckAndInsert($_POST["subject"], "subject", "verb");
CheckAndInsert($_POST["verb"], "subject", "verb");
```

Comment: Missing a double quote on first query, not point having the if giving out null change it to `if(mysqli_num_rows($query5) == 0) { rest of code` and get ride of the else. `printf("error: %s\n");` still useless as is.

Comment: Dictionary is the name of the database no the table hence the insert will fail, each column currently being used is a different table on that database.

Comment: And i first had it with all MySQL but I ran out of options on what to do so I just used MySQLi

Comment: @user3010773 you have far too many issues with your code I have listed some of them on my comments below your question try fixing those and u will get closer to the problem.

Comment: I fixed/addressed the problems you listed, nothing changed

Comment: @user3010773 obviously you didn't if u fixed what I had mention the first thing that would happen is that you code would die with error dictionary table does not exist since it didn't u didn't change it at all.

Comment: @Prix considering the problem was that i did not have 'id' as auto increment, it couldn't put a duplicate primary id, so it appears you didn't help much... and (at)logan Wayne, since you changed everything to mysqli, you get the answer

Comment: @user3010773 then tell me, how do you plan on `SELECT phrase FROM dictionary` when `dictionary` is the database and not the table? Not to mention if you properly had the `mysql_error()` it would tell you that `dictionary` does not exist given your currently database structure.